# Yii2: mysql query to get reminder about pending jobs?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Trying to implement query to get job_code,job_description,client_code  whose current status is not equal to PACKING or DISPATCH before 2 days of its due date-

```
$query = new Query;
        $todo = (new yii\db\Query())
        ->SELECT(['status','job_code','job_description','client_code'])
        ->from('create_job')
      ->where('status' LIKE 'PACKING' OR 'DISPATCH' AND 'approved_date' >= 'CURRENT_DATE' AND 'deadline' <  'CURRENT_DATE' + 'INTERVAL 2 DAY')
       ->all();
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
(new Query())->select(['status','job_code','job_description','client_code'])
->from('create_job')
->andWhere("status != 'PACKING'")
->andWhere("status != 'DISPATCH'")
->andWhere('deadline < (CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 2 DAY)')
->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT status,job_code,job_description,client_code
    from create_job
  where((status ='PACKING' OR status='DISPATCH') AND 
 (approved_date >= CURRENT_DATE AND deadline <  date_add(CURRENT_DATE ,INTERVAL 2 DAY))
```